# How to connect a headphone jack to this lm386

Tags: arduino, pcb, amplifier

[image]

I would like to attach a headphone jack to this board but I'm a bit confused as to how since the jacks I find have 5 pins but this only has 2 places for the headphone cables.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Show us the picture of the five pin jack.

Comment: @soosaisteven I added a picture of them

Comment: With a single LM386 you only get mono. So connect the pin labelled Out+ (or whatever) to both tip and ring on the connector, and Out- (or 0V or Ground) to the sleeve. And ignore the other two contacts, they are switches. If you want to wire up a speaker, you can wire it to either of them : then the speaker will be disconnected when you plug the headphones in.

Comment: @BrianDrummond so being mono will it play in both ears of the headphone or only one? Sorry I'm new to this and trying to learn

Comment: The tip of the plug will connect to one ear (left. I think), and the ring to the other ear.  The sleeve of the plug will be common to both ears.  Brian suggests connecting the amplifier output "hot" side to tip and ring, to drive both ears.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Joshua. When the guys ask for a picture of the jack they really expect to see the pinout (rather than a pile of parts at low magnification) or the pinout diagram from the datasheet (which you should link). Anyway, it looks as though you've got the info you require.

Comment: @transistor oh, I haven't actually gotten them yet just trying to do my research before they come in

Comment: There should be a datasheet, downloadable from wherever you're getting the sockets from. If there isn't, it's a good idea not to buy them... Anyway that would have the pinout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the connectors that you've pasted, they're probably 5 pinned for other reason, which may be for a better holding to PCB. Not all pins are always functional only for signals or voltage/current transmit.

[image]

On the other side, this module is for mono output only. It means, you can only listen to either left either right speaker.

How to connect? See on picture, but for connector, measure pins for sure!

[image]